# Union with Insidious bug

Tags: c++, arrays

Having a problem grasping that when we want to traverse a whole array and compare each value of the array with a number present in the array, say arr[0] then, why is it advised to initialize an int with arr[0], like int acomp =arr[0] and compare acomp with every integer present in the array than comparing every integer present in the array with arr[0]?
For eg., in the following code of union it was pointed out to me that Code 2 is better than Code 1, but I am not quite sure why.

```
int unionarr(int p, int q){            //Code 1
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        if(arr[i]==arr[p])
            arr[i]=arr[q];}

int unionarr(int p, int q){            //Code 2
    int pid=arr[p];
    int qid=arr[q];
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        if(arr[i]==pid)
            arr[i]=qid;}
```

Comment: `union` is a reserved keyword in C++ and what's the point of `int pid=arr[p]; int qid=arr[q];` if you don't use these two variables?

Comment: You mean `if(arr[i]==pid)` and `arr[i]=qid;`, don't you?

Comment: whoever told you that one is better than the other was lying, because [both wont compile](http://ideone.com/RlHRah)

Comment: Build both with optimization, check the generated assembly for differences.

Comment: Sorry, could you have a look at the revised program?

Comment: code looks better now, but still your title is very misleading, because there is no `union` in the code and its not clear what bug you refer to

Comment: if you mean Code 2 is better because it has used two local variable then probably i wont agree. Values are accessed directly from array in Code 1.

Answer (score 5):

It's a correctness issue. The assignment inside the `for` loop can modify array values. You might modify the very elements that are being used in the comparison or right-hand side of the assignment. That's why you must save them before entering the loop.

Comment: Thank you!
In case anyone is still not able to understand this answer,
assume arr[]={0,1,1,2}, p is 1, q is 3.
If we go by Code 1, the answer I'll get is {0,2,1,2} as arr[1] would change to 2, and when i becomes 2 in the for loop, it won't change as arr[2] is not equal to arr[p], as arr[1] has now become 2.
If we go by code 1, we'll get the correct answer that is, {0,2,2,2}.

Answer (score 0):

Making local copies pid, and qid of values which would otherwise have to be repeatedly looked up in the array is something of a performance optimisation.
However, I would be surprised if any modern compiler would fail to pick that up and do that optimisation implicitly.

Comment: Random thought: Isn't the compiler unable to optimize in the first code because of the aliasing possibility `&arr[i] == &arr[p] == &arr[q]`?

Answer (score 0):

Using https://godbolt.org/ you can compare the two. what you care about is the instruction inside the loop.

With Clang 4.0 the assembly is:

- Code 1

  ```
  movsxd  rax, dword ptr [rbp - 16]
  mov     ecx, dword ptr [4*rax + arr]
  movsxd  rax, dword ptr [rbp - 8]
  cmp     ecx, dword ptr [4*rax + arr]
  jne     .LBB0_4
  movsxd  rax, dword ptr [rbp - 12]
  mov     ecx, dword ptr [4*rax + arr]
  movsxd  rax, dword ptr [rbp - 16]
  mov     dword ptr [4*rax + arr], ecx
  ```
- Code 2

  ```
  movsxd  rax, dword ptr [rbp - 24]
  mov     ecx, dword ptr [4*rax + arr]
  cmp     ecx, dword ptr [rbp - 16]
  jne     .LBB0_4
  mov     eax, dword ptr [rbp - 20]
  movsxd  rcx, dword ptr [rbp - 24]
  mov     dword ptr [4*rcx + arr], eax
  ```